# Printing help for nested subparsers with required positional arguments

Tags: python

I ran into what appears to be a bug (though could just be misunderstood but expected behavior) in how argparse treats the help flag for nested subparsers.

A minimum viable reproduction is the following:

`main.py`:

```
import argparse
import sys

def get_subparser_a_1(p):
  p.add_argument('arg_a1_1', help='Second sublevel argument arg_a1_1.')

def get_subparser_a(p):
  subparsers = p.add_subparsers(dest='sublevel 2')

  a_1 = subparsers.add_parser('1', description='Second sublevel parser A1.', help='Second sublevel parser A1.')
  get_subparser_a_1(a_1)

  a_2 = subparsers.add_parser('2', description='Second sublevel parser A2.', help='Second sublevel parser A2.')

  p.add_argument('arg_a_1', help='First sublevel argument arg_a_1.')

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser('Top level parser.')
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='sublevel 1')

a = subparsers.add_parser('a', description='First sublevel parser A.', help='First sublevel parser A.')
get_subparser_a(a)

b = subparsers.add_parser('b', description='First sublevel parser B.', help='First sublevel parser B.')

parser.add_argument('arg_1', help='Top level argument arg_1.')

parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])
```

When running `main.py -h`, the help output is as expected:

```
usage: Top level parser. [-h] {a,b} ... pos_1

positional arguments:
  {a,b}
    a         First sublevel parser A.
    b         First sublevel parser B.
  arg_1       Top level argument arg_1.

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

Subsequently running `main.py a -h`, the help output is as expected:

```
usage: Top level parser. a [-h] {1,2} ... arg_a_1

First sublevel parser A.

positional arguments:
  {1,2}
    1         Second sublevel parser A1.
    2         Second sublevel parser A2.
  arg_a_1     First sublevel argument arg_a_1.

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

The positional argument `arg_1` is ignored, since the subparser `A` is triggered.

However, when subsequently running `main.py a 1 -h`, the parser fails:

```
usage: Top level parser. a [-h] {1,2} ... arg_a_1
Top level parser. a: error: the following arguments are required: arg_a_1
```

Although the top-level parser ignored the positional argument `arg_1` and continued with the `A` subparser, the `A` subparser does not similarly ignore the positional argument `arg_a_1` and continue with the `A1` sub-subparser; it requires that `arg_a_1` is provided.

Running `main.py a 1 -h any_value` then successfully prints the expected help message:

```
usage: Top level parser. a 1 [-h] arg_a1_1

Second sublevel parser A1.

positional arguments:
  arg_a1_1    Second sublevel argument arg_a1_1.

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

Is there a way to resolve this problem? I would like the `A` subparser to behave as the main parser, ignoring the positional argument `arg_a_1` and printing the help message for the `A1` sub-subparser.

Any ideas?